# Do I need to synchronize access to immutable types in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, thread-safety

Let's say I have this class:

```
class Zoo
{
    protected String bearName;
    protected Double trainerSalary;
    protected Integer monkeyCount;
}
```

Can one thread write to these fields, and another one read them, without requiring `synchronized` access to the `Zoo` object?

Note: these values can be treated separate from one another, so it doesn't matter that the `trainerSalary` is changed while the `monkeyCount` is read.

**EDIT**:

Just to clarify, the fields are **mutable**; only their referenced objects are **immutable**.

Comment: What makes these values "immutable"?   If you can write to them, they need to be protected by synchronization of some form.

Comment: @Rodney Gitzel: I think the implication is that the *objects* themselves are immutable. You can't hold a reference to a `String` and change the contents (you would need to create a new object).

Comment: @Rodney Gitzel String, Double and Integer are all immutable types in Java. Doing any work that changes them simply returns a new object.

Comment: It does not matter that Zoo uses immutable objects in its fields. That does not make Zoo immutable. Immutability implies that once created, you will not change anything in Zoo. Now, if Zoo were truly immutable then the answer to your question is "no, you do not need to syncronize access to Zoo".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Technically you need to make them `final`, `volatile` or read **and** write them using `synchronzied` to guarantee that the reader will read the most up-to-date value. As you have it right now, if one thread writes in a value, there's no guarantee that another thread will read the same value. This is because the the reading thread may see a cached valued. This is more likely with multi-core CPUs and various levels of cache.

A great book on this is [Java Concurrency in Practice](http://jcip.net/).

Comment: `volatile` or `synchronized` are the key to prevent two different threads getting different values from the same thread, at the same time.

Comment: May I suggest you to mention also the classes in java.util.concurrent.atomic package in your enumeration of alternatives? This is yet another way to do it without any explicit synchronization.

Answer (score 4):

Accesses and updates to the memory cells corresponding to fields of any type except long or double are guaranteed to be atomic [(see Concurrent Programming In Java)](http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/cpj/jmm.html). That's why one might expect that you don't need to synchronize read access to your fields. However, the Java memory model allows threads to cache previously read values in case you access them repeatedly so you should mark the fields as volatile to ensure that each thread sees the most recent values.

If you are sure that nobody will change the values of the fields, make them final. In that case, no volatile field is necessary.

Things are different if the values of the fields depend on each other. In that case, I'd recommend to use synchronized setters that ensure that the invariant of your class is not violated.

Comment: `Accesses and updates to the memory cells corresponding to fields of any type except long or double are guaranteed to be atomic` - really? I've never come across anything documenting this before.

Comment: Sorry, forget to mention the source. It's from Doug Leas 'Concurrent Programming in Java'

Comment: @Finbarr @Sebastian Zarnekow This comes actually from the [Java Language Specification, section 17.7 Non-Atomic Treatment of double and long](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/memory.html#17.7).

Answer (score 1):

As you've stated the class it's possible for another class in the same package to change these values. This class isn't immutable.

Now if you did something like

```
class Zoo
{
    protected final String bearName;
    protected final Double trainerSalary;
    protected final Integer monkeyCount;
}
```

Then the class would be immutable. If the logic of your program treats this class as immutable, then why not make it actually immutable?

Also, if multiple threads were checking and updating the same value then you could have issue. Say multiple threads were checking and updating monkeyCount, then there is a good chance monkeyCount would end up incorrect because there is nothing that is forcing these check and updates to occur atomically.

Answer (score 1):

My 2 cents, from "The Java Programming Language", 4 ed., 14.10.2 :
"There is a common misconception that shared access to immutable objects does not require any synchronization because the state of the object never changes. This is a misconception in general because it relies on the assumption that a thread will be guaranteed to see the
initialized state of the immutable object, and that need not be the case. The problem is that, while the shared object is immutable, the reference used to access the shared object is itself shared and often mutable - consequently, a correctly synchronized program must synchronize access to that shared reference, but often programs do not do this, because programmers do not recognize the need to do it. For example, suppose one thread creates a String object and stores a reference to it in a static field. A second thread then uses that
reference to access the string. There is no guarantee, based on what we've discussed so far, that the values written by the first thread when constructing the string will be seen by the second thread when it accesses the string."

Answer (score 0):

If those variables are indeed independent, then no, you do not need synchronization. However, as you note, if you had

```
protected Integer monkeysLeft;
protected Integer monkeysEatenByBears;
```

where the two variables are logically connected, you would want synchronized access to the pair of them.

Comment: They need synchronization anyway if one thread is writing to them and another thread is reading them as he suggests.